# Number of configurations of a polygon with n equal sides as a function of n

Tags: geometry

Hi this is my first time posting anything here.
I thought up this problem while in the shower, it's literally a shower thought. I just don't quite know how to word it, so I'll try my best:

What is the number of configurations of a n-sided polygon with equal side lengths? By "configurations," I mean order of angle types as you go around. C = concave angle, V = convex angle.

[visual explaination of the series (sorry about the bad handwriting)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKIMM.png)

I'm not quite sure how to word the problem. The polygon can't be stretched at all, or else the third configuration for n=6 would be possible. So the polygon must somehow stay somewhat normal. Perhaps one way is to say no vertices can be outside of the area of the regular n-gon. I'm definitely not experienced enough to take on this problem, so I pose it to all of you!

So far, I have the series 0,0,1,1,2,2,5,7,... but I don't know how to write it as a function of n. I tried plugging these numbers into OEIS, but none of the matches mentioned polygons.

Good luck and thanks!

Comment: I have little idea what you meant by the hexagon configuration. Isn't the third figure perfectly valid, just by reflecting the two "side corners" of the first figure?

Comment: Well, the two reflected side corners would meet in the middle of the hexagon. It's width would be zero at that point. Not sure if you can really call that a polygon.

Comment: They met when the original hexagon was regular. But we consider general equilateral hexagons, don't we? If you "pinch" the "sides" of the regular hexagon with your fingers, slightly before the two corners met, we have a hexagon with two concave angles. (I may properly call that figure "bow tie")

Comment: I don't know how to best word my question, but that would require the whole thing to be "stretched" vertically. This is against the problem because none of the verticies can lie outside of the region that a regular hexagon would occupy

Comment: I think a better way of wording my problem is that a different configuration would be if you folded it along a line between two corners where the folded sections don't intersect, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Okay, I see your point. One more question: do you require the polygons to be contained in the regular polygon, or (imposing stricter condition) obtained by reflecting (a sequence of) consecutive sides into its interior?

Comment: I think it can be a series of reflections, so if you have a 100-gon, and you folded along the line of points 1 and 45, lines between those points would be concave. But you could have an inverse reflection somewhere along that, making a portion of the lines that are concave to be convex again. And so on.

Comment: Okay, it sounds clearer now. Let me think about it.